# Объединение двух таблиц в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите допереть,  есть две таблиц,

`orgtypes` - Содержит типы организаций

```
id |name         |
--------------------------
1  |Организация 1|
1  |Организация 1|
1  |Организация 1|
1  |Организация 1|
```

`orgs` - содержит выбранные типы организаций

```
id |user_id  | types
--------------------------
1  |1        |1
1  |1        |3
1  |2        |2       
1  |2        |4
```

Нужно получить таблицу

```
id | user      | ogrs
--------------------------
1  | 1         | Организация 1,Организация 3
1  | 2         | Организация,Организация 4
```

Так вот. НЕ могу понять вроде `JOIN` не подходит так как у них нет общей колонки, `(SELECT orgs.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(orgs.types) FROM orgs  WHERE orgs.types IN( SELECT orgtypes.name,orgtypes.name FROM orgtypes))` ?? не понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  orgs.id AS id,
  orgs.user_id AS user_id,
  CONCAT_GROUP(orgtypes.name) AS ors
FROM
  orgs
LEFT JOIN
  orgtypes
ON
  ors.types = orgtypes.id
GROUP BY
  orgs.user_id
```

Не обязательно, чтобы ключи назывались одинаково, вы просто не сможете воспользоваться ключевым словом `USING`, но сможете заменить его ключевым словом `ON`. Вы можете связать таблицы через первичный ключ таблицы типов `orgtypes.id` и внешний ключ организаций связующей таблицы `ors.types`.

Так как вам требуется вывести организации через запятую, удобно сгруппировать результаты по пользователям `GROUP BY orgs.user_id` и воспользоваться функцией `CONCAT_GROUP()` для вывода списка организаций в пределах каждой из полученных групп.

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый чел, вот так подредактировал и как надо работает SELECT
  orgs.id AS id,
  orgs.user_id AS uid,
  GROUP_CONCAT(orgtypes.name) AS orgs
FROM
  orgs
LEFT JOIN
  orgtypes
ON
  orgs.val = orgtypes.id
GROUP BY
  orgs.user_id